# JS Object array property initializer / optional chaining

Tags: javascript, lodash

To initialize an Object array property and then push values seems to be a two step approach. Is there an optimal one line approach in ES6? Example of the issue is in the  `appendError(prop, error)` method below.

**Question:**

Is there one line or more concise approach with JS or lodash?

Future optional chaining seems solve the problem, but is there a solution today? PHP allows `$array[prop][] = val;`

```
  class Errors {
    constructor(fields ) {
        this.errors = {};
    }

    /**
     * Clear one or all error fields.
     *
     * @param {string} prop | example: "email"
     * @param {string} error | example: "Invalid email"
     */
    appendError(prop, error) {
        /* Set key and empty array if property doest exist */
        if (!this.has(prop)) this.errors[prop] = [];
        /* then Push value */
        this.errors[prop].push(error);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if an errors exists for the given field.
     *
     * @param {string} prop
     */
    has(prop) {
        return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(prop);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) to assign an empty array, if the property value id `undefined`:

```
(this.errors[prop] ??= []).push(error);
```

Example:

```js
class Errors {
  constructor(fields) {
    this.errors = {};
  }

  appendError(prop, error) {
    (this.errors[prop] ??= []).push(error);
  }
}

const errors = new Errors;

errors.appendError('a', 'a');

errors.appendError('a', 'b');

console.log(errors.errors);
```

Comment: Ori thank you!  Logical nullish assignment (??=) makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse `||` for that:

```js
this.errors[prop]?.push(error) || (this.errors[prop] = [error]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Im perfectly ok using operator as it a bit based approach which works.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like:

```
appendError(prop, error) {
    (this.error[prop] = this.error[prop]||[]) && this.error[prop].push(error) && this.error[prop];
}
```